# Android Playback Engine in Unity

Tags: unity, android

Should I install Android Playback Engine in Unity if I am going to make games for Android? What the Android Playback Engine is used for?

I got the question when decided to reinstall Unity and met it:

[image]

I tried to figure out what it is used for on my own, but found almost nothing. It seems that I am a bad seeker. I found just [this](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/android-GettingStarted.html):

**Movie playback**

Movie textures are not supported on Android, but full-screen streaming playback is provided via scripting functions.

Is it just about showing you the game backwards? (з

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Android Build support` is self-explanatory. If you want to build games for Android, you **must** select `Android Build support`.

To play video on Android (and iOS), MovieTextures are not supported natively. You have to use either a plugin on the asset store or the `Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie` function : https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Handheld.PlayFullScreenMovie.html

Comment: If I did not check the `Android Build Support` during the installation can I install it somehow independently or should I reinstall the Unity?

Comment: Try to execute again the installer. I think Unity won't reinstall from scratch if you only select `Android Build Support`, but I may be wrong.